# On "beautifully" in French

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes, suffixes

Voici une question apparemment stupide...

Pourquoi ne peut-on dire ***beaument**, sur le modèle *beautifully*, si on peut faire ça avec tous les autres adjectifs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On ne dirait pas *<s>*beaument*</s>, mais *[bellement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bellement)*. Les adverbes sont des mots savants et sont en général construits sur une racine proche de l'étymologie. L'adjectif *beau* vient d'une racine *bell-*, et a encore une forme *[bel](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bel#Forme_d.E2.80.99adjectif)* au masculin, mais qui n'est utilisée que quand l'adjectif est avant un nom qui commence par une voyelle. La forme *beau* vient d'une transformation du suffixe -*el* où le *-l* est devenu un *-u* et a changé la prononciation de la voyelle qui le précède ; c'est la même transformation que dans les pluriels *-al* → *-aux* par exemple.

Sauf que *bellement* n'existe quasiment plus en français moderne. La [deuxième édition du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](https://archive.org/stream/fre_b1886001#page/n165/mode/2up) signalait déjà en 1718 le mot seulement dans le sens de « doucement, lentement » et seulement en langage familier.

En général, l'adverbe correspondant à *beau* est ***joliment***, même dans des cas où l'on n'utiliserait pas l'adjectif *joli*.

> Ces paroles sont *belles*. Ces paroles sont *joliment tournées*.

Il peut y avoir d'autres adverbes. Par exemple, si le contexte implique un sens esthétique, *bien* peut correspondre à *beau*.

> Ce portrait a une *belle* composition. Ce portrait est *bien* composé.

Answer (score 6):

L'adverbe de *beau/bel/belle* est *[bellement](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bellement/8677)*.

Mais il n'est jamais utilisé, il est considéré comme [vieilli ou littéraire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/bellement).

Comment: (Just adding that most if not all adverbs formed on adjectives use the feminine, for future derivations by the asker!)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Never noticed that, I'll pay attention from now on.

Comment: +1, not least of all for the good-natured wordplay (unfortunately now deleted, but the upvote is, of course, yours to keep) alluding to goats and [the similar-sounding word for the sound they make](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%AAlement)! cc: @User26328

Answer (score 2):

And another explanation is this:

It is *bellement*, not ***beaument**, because French adverbs always attach *-ment* to the feminine form of their corresponding adjectives.

And they do so because, etymologically, *-ment* comes from the Latin word *mēns* (*mind*), which is a feminine noun in this language from which French is ultimately derived.